# How send 2 xml request soap?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap

I have a list with two strings of XML, here is the C# code:

```
 string sb = "";
List<string> listGamme = new List<string>();
sb = ("<?xml....") ;//1st listGamme
listGamme.Add(sb);
sb = ("<?xml..."); //2nd listGamme
listGamme.Add(sb);
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("urlofmy.asmx");
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "URLSOAPACTION");
req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
req.Accept = "text/xml";
req.Method = "POST";


                using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
                {

                    using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                    {
                         foreach (string gamme in listGamme)
                            {

                                 stmw.Write(gamme);

                             }   

                     }

                }

    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader srreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

adding foreach inside de second using give me error 400 bad request :) , and if the 1st **listGamme** or 2nd **listGamme** is  “comment out”  the code work !, what wrong in my code ??

Comment: Is there some reason you can't simply use "Add Service Reference"? See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a loop in your code to send request one by one. You can not send both request simeltaneously,  if your wsdl is not permiting it.

Check out your request message format in wsdl whether it is taking request as string list as you have defined in your code?

For each string in your list repeat following code

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("urlofmy.asmx");
```

req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "URLSOAPACTION");
req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
req.Accept = "text/xml";
req.Method = "POST";

```
            using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
            {

                using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                {
                     foreach (string gamme in listGamme)
                        {

                             stmw.Write(gamme);

                         }   

                 }

            }

WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader srreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Also you will get multiple response for each xml request.

One more thing, can you paste your request message structure from wsdl. May be you can send multiple rquest in single request message(depends upon your wsdl request messaage structure)

Edited code:

```
string sb = "";
List<string> listGamme = new List<string>();
sb = ("<?xml....") ;//1st listGamme
listGamme.Add(sb);
sb = ("<?xml..."); //2nd listGamme
listGamme.Add(sb);

foreach (string gamme in listGamme)
                        {
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("urlofmy.asmx");
    req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "URLSOAPACTION");
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    req.Accept = "text/xml";
    req.Method = "POST";


            using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
            {

                using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                {

                             stmw.Write(gamme); 

                 }

            }

    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader srreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
}
```

Comment: how applying loop to send request one by one ?

Comment: i get this message  _**System.ArgumentException: Stream was not writable**_

Comment: please paste your wsdl here. I need only request message structure from it.